# I am making a Pythagoras calculator but I keep in getting the same message"invalid syntax"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a Pythagoras calculator but I keep in getting the same message"invalid syntax"
I am new to coding so I have only created what I thought should tell the user the missing side and I would be very grateful if you could explain to me what I have done wrong.The  message says "invalid syntax" and the highlights the first colons after 'if x == 1'.

```
# This should ask the user to pick an option

menu="Pythagoras Calculator:\n\
1. Find a hypotenuse?\n\
2. Find another side?\n\
9. Exit\n"


x = int(input(menu))

if x == 1:
    a = int(input("what is the other side?(cm)"))
    b = int(input("what is the last side?(cm)"))
    import math
    print("Hypotenuse=",math.sqrt((a**2)+(b**2)))

elif x == 2:
    c = int(input("what is the hypotenuse?(cm)"))
    d = int(input("what is the otherside?(cm)"))
    import math
    print("Other side=",math.sqrt((c**2)-(d**2)))

elif x == 9:
    print("Good Bye")
```

Comment: It would be good if you could format the code properly. But for starters x= int(input(menu) needs a final closing bracket

Comment: `int(input(menu)` has missing closing bracket.

Comment: thank you for pointing out my typo  but what do you mean by "format code properly" ?

Comment: Also, lose the extra import math statements. You just need one on the top of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I'm still getting the same problem.Any ideas?

Comment: @woli123  when you add code to a stack overflow question, highlight your code and indent using the code button on the text editor. It makes your code more clear.

Comment: @Woli123, what is your problem now? When running the code as it now, it does calculate the hypotenuse or other side. It doesn't loop, but you state is has "the same problem"?  If the typo fixed your problem, please approve the given answer. If not, clarify what else is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a closing bracket to the x= int(input(menu) line

So it should be x= int(input(menu))

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to coding, I thought you might like something a little bit more elaborate on your code.

Your code works fine with the added closing bracket on my machine.
Here are a few suggestions that might help you improving on it from my point of view:

- load math module at the beggining of your program - although, if you can keep it that way, and it would be fine in some conditions (like if you were concerned about the performance impact of loading math module when it isn't needed). More on that, you can avoid using math module if you just want the square root: `((a**2)+(b**2))**0.5` should do the trick.
- Very important: check user input. You cannot make square root of negative integers. So you would better do

  ```
  c = int(input("what is the hypotenuse?(cm)"))
  d = int(input("what is the otherside?(cm)"))
  assert d < c, "The otherside cannot be greater than the hypothenuse"
  import math
  print("Other side=",math.sqrt((c**2)-(d**2)))
  ```

Always ensure user's input. This is one of the greatest source of problems in programs. The same goes for the Menu.
Check that user's input is either 1, 2 or 9. You could design something to ensure that the user will type either 1, 2 or 9 or will be prompted again.

```
#With a printMenu function, you can print the menu again if you want to
def printMenu():
    menu="Pythagoras Calculator:\n\
          1. Find a hypotenuse?\n\
          2. Find another side?\n\
          9. Exit\n"
    print(menu)

#By setting x to None initially, you allow the following while loop
# to be executed at least once.
x = None
previouslyBad=False # This will be a flag in order to know if user got it wrong the first time
printMenu()

#With a loop, user will be asked for input again and again unless
# he uses the solutions you wanted him to use.
while x not in [1, 2, 9]:
    try:
        if not previouslyBad:
             x = int(input("Please choose a functionnality (e.g.: 1) "))
        else: 
             x = int(input("Please enter either 1, 2 or 9 "))
    #If you only use except without specifying ValueError,
    # user won't be able to use Ctrl+C to exit your program and will be
    # stuck in your menu. That is why you need to use two 
    # except statement.
    except ValueError:
        x = None
    except:
        raise
    previouslyBad = True #If the loop loops more than once, it should be aware of it

if x == 1:
    try:
        a = int(input("what is the other side?(cm)"))
        b = int(input("what is the last side?(cm)"))

    #Would you like to ensure entered values were int and not raise
    # error, you could use a similar strategy I implemented up with the
    # menu. 
    except ValueError:
        raise
    print("Hypotenuse=",((a**2)+(b**2))**0.5) # Using math.sqrt is fine too. But lazy loading indicated you would focus on performance. This might be slightly faster since it doesn't need any module loading.

elif x == 2:
    try:
        c = int(input("what is the hypotenuse?(cm)"))
        d = int(input("what is the otherside?(cm)"))
    except ValueError:
        raise
    #Assert here allows you to ensure user won't try squarerooting a
    # a negative value. 
    assert d <= c, "The otherside cannot be greater than the hypothenuse"
    print("Other side=",((c**2)-(d**2))**0.5)

elif x == 9:
    print("Good Bye")
```